# Using getChildHtml() to add a block in footer.phtml [SOLVED]

Tags: layout, blocks

I found a lot of similar titles but none of them help me out of my issue.

I'm about to insert a block into the footer section on **all pages** so I added below code at the end of:

> app/design/frontend/company/theme/layout/local.xml

just before the `</layout>` tag.

```
<!-- Instagram Scroller -->
<default> <!-- to display on all pages -->
    <!-- if name="head" exists then put in the existing tag -->
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/instashow/jquery.instashow.packaged.js</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="instascroller_script" template="instascroller/script.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

And I put my content in

> app/design/frontend/company/theme/template/instascroller/script.phtml

Then I put below code in

> app/design/frontend/company/theme/template/page/html/footer.phtml

```
<div class="instascroller">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('instascroller_script'); ?>
</div>
```

> Then **Flush the cache**

## ---- SOLVED ----

Thanks to everyone who viewed, commented, answered this question.

First of all, I should place the `<reference name="footer">` in the `<default>` tag. This solved my issue of not appearing **on all pages**.

Secondly, I should put `<action method="addItem">` in the existing `<reference name="head">` tag but I mistakenly created another one.

At last, I forgot to **flush the cache**.

I updated my question and wish this can help others.

*Again thanks to everyone.*

Comment: Your script.phtm file content will be show only in instagram/scroller/index action once you run.

Comment: You want to display it on all pages or only your custom page?

Comment: @s-h-patel, on all pages.

Comment: I changed `<instagram_scroller>` to `<default>` and confirmed `instascroller/script.phtml` is placed under `template/` and `js/instashow/jquery.instashow.packaged.js` is under `skin/frontend/company/theme/` but `var_dump( $this->getBlockHtml('instascroller_script') )` still returns `string(0) ""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handle you are using belongs to a specific page, so your content will be showing on instagram/scroller page only. Please check it on the page.

For displaying it on all pages, Please call it using the following code.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/instashow/jquery.instashow.packaged.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="instascroller_script" template="instascroller/script.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

You have placed the template file at wrong path.Please put the template file at the following path:

```
app/design/frontend/company/theme/template/instascroller/script.phtml
```

Clear the cache for the changes to be displayed.

Comment: It doesn't work. Could it be anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

1) Your are missing in your layout handle

```
<instagram_scroller> //here the layout handle is not correct, it should be like something like <instagram_scroller_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/instashow/jquery.instashow.packaged.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="core/template" name="instascroller_script" template="instascroller/script.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</instagram_scroller>
```

2) The layout handle is constructed like this: `<routerName_controllerName_actionName>`

3) You are also missing in template path, you put it in: `app/design/frontend/company/theme/template/instascroller/script.phtml` instead `app/design/frontend/company/theme/instascroller/script.phtml`

4) You put a JS file in : `skin/frontend/company/theme/js/instashow/jquery.instashow.packaged.js`

5) And use `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('instascroller_script'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I changed `<instagram_scroller>` to `<default>` as I want my code appear **on all pages**. `instascroller/script.phtml` is for sure under `app/design/frontend/company/theme/template/`. `JS` files are at appropriate position. But I still get nothing with `<?php var_dump( $this->getBlockHtml('instascroller_script') ); ?>` in the `page/html/footer.phtml`. I use `var_dump` because I want see at least the script has been run in `footer.phtml`. The result is `string(0) ""` which means `getBlockHtml` is called but can't find `instascroller_script`?

Comment: For All pages yes you have to put <default> instead, you did not specify it in the question. For getBlockHtml () its not possible it should work, maybe you are missing in a block type !

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention it in the first place. It works then after I flushed the cache. I need to be more careful and pay more attention to details.